# How do i fix my bash script output for checking if user's directories exist

Tags: linux, bash, script

```
grep -E -v '^(halt|sync|shutdown)' /etc/passwd | awk -F: '($7 != "'"$(which
nologin)"'" && $7 != "/bin/false") { print $1 " " $6 }' | while read -r user
dir; do
            if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then
                    echo "Fail: see below"
                    echo "The home directory ($dir) of user $user does not exist."
            else
                    echo "pass"
            fi
done
```

how can i fix my output so that the first if echo"Fail: see below" only prints once while the second print any user that doesn't exist. My else statement just prints itself too, how do I stop it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled with this, because I've never programmed in such a way as to use inner-shells before (which destroyed the output I was needing).  I came up with the following, which is slightly less efficient, but I expect will make no discernable difference in the vast majority of cases.  Also, this assumes that there are no spaces in the home directory :

```
#! /bin/bash

failcount=0

for each in `grep -E -v '^(async|shutdown)' /etc/passwd | awk -F: '($7 != "'"$(which nologin)"'" && $7 != "/bin/false") { print $1 ":" $6 }'`
do
        user=`echo $each | cut -f1 -d":"`
        dir=`echo $each | cut -f2 -d":"`

        if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then
                if [ $failcount -eq 0 ]
                then
                        echo "Fail: see below"
                fi
                echo "The home directory ($dir) of user $user does not exist."
                failcount=$(( $failcount + 1 ))
        fi
done


if [ $failcount -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "Pass"
fi
```